# The Swift server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. Error thrown in sroucekites.js:55

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:6004/bdcbe0c5-eb0f-4efd-9be4-0a308337ba23
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
/Users/cgriffin/.vscode/extensions/vknabel.vscode-swift-development-environment-2.12.3/out/sourcekites-server/sourcekites.js:55
        throw err;
        ^

Error: spawn . EACCES
    at Process.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'spawn .',
  path: '.',
  spawnargs: []
}
```

I'm running:
VS Code version: 1.86.2
on an M1 iMac running Sonoma 14.3.1 with latest Xcode installed. I have verified that the command line tools are installed. I have also uninstalled any Swift plugins. I see that the path is '.' but no indication what it was trying to spawn.

Comment: It'll be almost impossible to diagnose something like this without much more debugging, but  when I see "EACCES" my first guess is there's a permission issue. My first guess is that VSCode itself doesn't have full disk/write/execute access to the folders you're  trying to run the xcode CLI commands on. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the old "vknabel.vscode-swift-development-environment" extension was still getting loaded even though it didn't show up in the extensions list. Edited the extensions.json file and removed the entry. Works now.